# What can my ISP see when I use an elite proxy server in my browser?

Tags: networking, proxy, privacy, isp

Let's say I've configured my chrome browser to use an elite proxy for browsing downloading etc,. What information can my ISP see about the connection? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define an "elite proxy"?

Comment: The opposite of a noob proxy, obviously

Comment: @qasdfdsaq i never heard about noob proxy before, are you sure it is HW & SW, "noob" feature sounds more about gaming than technical language...

Answer (score 2):

An ISP can see **everything** that goes over the wire - encrypted traffic just won't make sense (for example, they could see you're looking at your online banking, but couldn't read your bank statements), for non-encrypted traffic, they could see and read everything.

In short, if your connection to your "elite" proxy is encrypted, your browsing history is safe, if not, then your ISP *could* read your entire browsing history.